# Are the terminologies of score and principal component in PCA equivalent?

Tags: pca, terminology

I am confused with the terminologies of score and principal component in PCA, it seems they are equivalent but there is also some difference. Could anyone explain to me?

Comment: Principal component is a (constructed, as a linear combination) variable. Its case values are called its PC scores. Sometimes, eigenvectors (or principal directions, principal axes) are called "principal components" too. Eigenvector per se is the coefficients in the aforementioned linear combination.